# jQuery Accordion: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#/x=y]

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I have seen tons of other questions on this error message, but from what I can tell they are all for improperly-escaped quotes in selectors. 
 In my case, I'm not (intentionally, at least) using any selectors at all. 
 When I open my page www.example.com/sp I get no errors, but when I open www.example.com/sp#/x=y I this error when I call `$('.accordion').accordion();`.

Here is the line in jquery.accordion that bothers me: `var d = (location.hash) ? c.find('a[href=' + location.hash + ']')[0] : c.find('li.current a')[0];`

It appears that jquery accordion is assuming it can interpret `location.hash` as a selector, but I use it for different things.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating it wrong and will not be treated as a valid value.

Try this:

```
c.find('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]')
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. The code is inside jquery accordion it is not mine.

Comment: @skb well, if you think of it, it is also helpful. You can modify it though just to solve your problem.

Comment: you mean modify the source code for jQuery.accordion?

Comment: @skb yeah? Since you said that's where the issue is? and you're trying to disable such error? then that's where the error is coming from, just modify the line that you're saying from accordion and I think that will work from a javascript perspective.

Comment: thx, I've marked your answer as accepted. initially felt weird modifying jQuery directly, but I'm using such an old version so I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @skb not really sure if this has been updated from the newest version, however, if suits your need ,feel free to do so, it won't kill anything anyway :D Thanks!!